# How can I use conditional formatting to set a cells colour equal to another cells colour?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm trying to organize some numbers (related to character experience use in a tabletop RPG), and I would like to be able to colour one cell by just copying the colour of the cell to its immediate right. Effectively, I would like conditional formatting that says something like "B1.Colour = C1.Colour", but I can't seem to find any documentation supporting this.

Is this possible? If no, is there another simple way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is **not** possible to set the color based on color within formulas. you can do this only via script. what you can do with formulas is:

- you can extend it like this:

  [image: 0]
- or you can offset it like this:

  [image: 0]

Comment: Thank you! It seems I will have to learn how to use scripts in google sheets to pull this off then.